# If nobody needs reliable messaging on transport level, how to implement reliable PubSub on business level?

Tags: events, architecture, domain-driven-design, publish-subscribe

This question is mostly out of curiosity. I read [this article about WS-ReliableMessaging by *Marc de Graauw*](https://www.infoq.com/articles/no-reliable-messaging) some time ago and agreed that reliable messaging should be applied on the business level as whenever possible.

Now, the question is, he explains clearly what his approach is in a point-to-point fashion. However, I fail to see how you could implement reliable messaging on the business level in a Publish/Subscribe situation.

I will try to demonstrate the difference by showing commands (point-to-point) vs. events (publish/subscribe). Note that these examples are highly simplified.

---

**Command**: Transfer(uniqueId, amount, sourceAccount, recipientAccount)

If the account holder sends this transfer, he could wait for the confirmation `MoneyTransferred` (assuming this event will contain a reference to the `uniqueId` in the `Transfer` command.

If the account holder doesn't received the `MoneyTransferred` within a given timeout period, he could send the same command again. (of course assuming the command processor is idempotent)

So I see how reliable messaging could work on business level in a point-to-point fashion.

---

Now, say we the previous command succeeded and produced a `MoneyTransferred` event. Somewhere in the system we have an event processor (`MoneyTransferEmailNotifier`) that handles `MoneyTransferred` events and will send an email notification to the recipient of the transfer.

This `MoneyTransferEmailNotifier` is subscribed to `MoneyTransferred` events. But note that system sending the `MoneyTransferred` event does not really care who or how many listeners there are to this event. The whole point is the decoupling here. I raise an event and don't care if there zero or 20 listeners that subscribe to this event.

**At this point, if there is no reliable messaging (minimally at-least-once-delivery) provided by the infrastructure, how can we prevent the loss of the `MoneyTransferred` event? I do want the recipient to get his e-mail notification.**

I fail to see how any real 'business-level' solution will resolve this.

**(1)** One of the solutions I can think of is by explicitly subscribing to events on 'business level' and thereby bypassing any infrastructure component. But aren't we at that moment introducing infrastructure in our business?

**(2)** The other 'solution' would be by introducing a process manager that does something like this:

1. PM receives `Transfer` command
2. PM forwards `Transfer` command to the accounts subsystem
3. If successful, sends command `SendEmailNotification(recipient)` to the notification subsystem

This does seem to be the solution that DDD prescribes, correct? But doesn't this introduce more coupling?

What do you think?

### Edit 2016-04-16

Maybe the root question is a little bit more simplistic: **If you do not have an infrastructural component that ensures at-least or exactly-once delivery, how can you ensure (when you're in an at-most-once infrastructure) that your events emitted will be received?**

Not all events need to be delivered but there are many that are key (like the example of sending the confirmation email)

Comment: So, discussions about events polling is out of the question, right? Your question is solely about pub/sub right?

Comment: Yes it's purely about pub/sub. I gave the command example as reference material. Also maybe it is easier to ignore any UI in this topic. Let's assume we're talking purely backend services (one subscribing to the other).

Comment: "This does seem to be the solution that DDD prescribes, correct?" Note that DDD is  comunication infrastructure agnostic. It doesn't care how messages/events/commands receive the Aggregates or Sagas. This is purely an implementation design.

Comment: "how can we prevent the loss of the MoneyTransferred event" - what do you mean by the "loss" of the event? The event is never loss if using Event sourcing.

Comment: I'm not applying event sourcing or whatsoever in this case. But with your answer and the answer from VoiceOfUnreason I think I've found the flaw in my reasoning. At-most-once delivery is by definition not suitable for PubSub. So I have to either use at-least-once semantics or use something other than PubSub

Comment: You could still use an event log (not event sourcing) and use it for polling.

Answer (score 1):

> If nobody needs reliable messaging on transport level, how to implement reliable `PubSub` on business level?

The original article does not state that "nobody needs reliable messaging on transport level", it states that the ordering of messages should be enforced at the business level because, **in some cases**, *if* this ordering is an important characteristic of the business.

In any case, `PubSub` is at the infrastructure level, you can't say that you implement `PubSub` at the business level. It doesn't make sense.

But then how you could ensure only-once-delivery at the business level? By using a `Saga/Process manager`. On of the important responsibilities of them is exactly that. You can combine that with idempotent `Aggregates`. Also, you could identify terms that emphasis ordering from the `Ubiquitous language` like `transaction phase` and include them in your domain models (for example as properties of the events).

> If you do not have an infrastructural component that ensures at-least
>   or exactly-once delivery, how can you ensure (when you're in an
>   at-most-once infrastructure) that your events emitted will be
>   received?
>   If you do not have at-least-once then you could use the first event that it is initiating the hole process. I would use event polling and a Saga that ensure that every important step in the process is reached at the right moment.

In your case, as the sending of the email is an important business aspect, I would include it as a step in the process.

Comment: The title and the first alinea do seem to state this. Well, he doesn't include the "transport level" part but that is what I read between the lines. "The reverse is true: from a business perspective, there is absolutely no need for reliable messaging."

But I agree with you that PubSub doesn't make sense on the business level. That is what my question is about.

Comment: However, say that you'd use a `Process Manager`, I believe you could ensure at-least-once delivery by using confirmations. But this won't work in a PubSub situation unless you would keep track of the subscribers in the Process Manager. Do you agree?

Comment: Not quite. Process Manager is itself a subscriber, it does not have a list of subscribers. That list is held by the PubSub infrastructure.. If the **first event** in the process is "lost" then the process cannot be started which is bad.

Comment: @sdegroot I thought that the question is about PubSub, not Event Polling. In polling the messages are never "lost". You can always query the list of all previous events in order.

Comment: The question is about decoupling using PubSub indeed. Because that is the way that seemed to make most sense. However, if PubSub is the wrong solution for the problem then, well, let's change the solution.

The goal is to separate responsibility. Sending the e-mail is a separate responsibility that the rest of the system should be unaware of. Shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

> This MoneyTransferEmailNotifier is subscribed to MoneyTransferred events. But note that system sending the MoneyTransferred event does not really care who or how many listeners there are to this event. The whole point is the decoupling here. I raise an event and don't care if there zero or 20 listeners that subscribe to this event.

Your tangle, I believe, is here - that only the publish subscribe middleware can deliver events to where they need to go.

Greg Young covers this in his talk on [polyglot data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hv2dKtPq0ME) [(slides)](https://speakerdeck.com/rigadevday/greg-young-polyglot-data).

Summarizing: the pub/sub middleware is *in the way*.  A pull based model, where consumers retrieve data from the durable event store gives you a reliable way to retrieve the messages from the store.  So you pull the data from the store, and then use the business level data to recognize previous work as before.

For instance, upon retrieving the MoneyTransferred event with its business data, the process manager looks around for an EmailSent event with matching business data.  If the second event is found, the process manager knows that at least one copy of the email was successfully delivered, and no more work need be done.

The push based models (pub/sub, UDP multicast) become latency optimizations -- the arrival of the push message tells the subscriber to pull earlier than it normally would.

In the extreme push case, you pack into the pushed message enough information that the subscriber(s) can act upon it immediately, and trust that the idempotent handling of the message will prevent problems when the redundant copy of the message arrives on the slower channel.

Comment: That is a very interesting way to look at the problem! Thanks.
Using this way you don't have any necessity for a message-bus whatsoever (the latency optimisation aside of course).  You maybe would need some more querying options in your event store. Something that matches the topic bindings in RabbitMQ maybe.
Alternatively, Kafka could be an interesting option for this. What do you think?